# How connect to ubuntu server if it is with internal IP

Tags: networking

I have ubuntu server in my home and I want get acces it from elswhere. I don't have public adress IP on my ubuntu server so I can't reach it from internet. I have static DNS etc. I heard of hamachi but I must install this on every computer which I want to connect to my ubuntu server at home. I want only acces to terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup a [reverse ssh tunnel](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/setting-up-a-reverse-ssh-tunnel/5779944)

```
ssh -nNT -R 1100:local.mydomain.com:22 user@remote.mydomain.com
```

What this does is forwards any connections on port 1100 of the remote server to port 22 of the local system. You'd have to prepare this connection in advance, and it is not as reliable as a VPN.

If you want more reliability (ssh connection might get dropped), go for openvpn.

Comment: But I need server with public IP. I don't have any.

Comment: You can try out [pagekite](http://pagekite.net/wiki/Howto/SshOverPageKite/) or [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/) for that purpose. Just remember to forward your ssh port(22) instead of web(80).

Comment: Thanks! I installed localtunnel and I get adress even but when I try connect from another computer using putty then I get "access denied" after typing password.

Comment: I tried ssh from ubuntu and I get "Permission denied, please try later".

Comment: Are you using the correct username?

Comment: Yes, I even make another user and problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a reverse NAT rule in your router/NAT/firewall so that any connection to your router from outside on a port will be translated to a another machines address and port in your local network.

So port 22 on your router could translat to port 22 on your server.  Then you just need to register in your DNS your server with the global IPv4 address of your router.

Or you can set up IPv6 and then all your machines could have proper global adressers.  But the machine you then connect from also need to be on a IPv6 net.  Don't forget to set up firewall on your IPv6-router and your machines.  Which is quite easy to do with ufw.